# Configuring Apache/2.4.10 mod_wsgi and virtualenv python 3.6 for flask 1.0.3 on debian 8.11

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask

my apache configuration file has:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 

ServerName localhost
WSGIDaemonProcess tasks4 python-path=/home/user1/Projects/tasks/tasks/tasks/wsgi.py:/home/user1/env_rt_dms:/home/user1/env_rt_dms/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user1/Projects/tasks/tasks/tasks/wsgi.py

WSGIPassAuthorization On

Alias /rt1 /home/user1/Projects/tasks/tasks/tasks/static/

<Directory /home/user1/Projects/tasks/tasks>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    WSGIProcessGroup tasks4
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the wsgi file:

```
#! /home/user1/env_rt_dms/bin
import sys, os

activate_this = '/home/user1/env_rt_dms/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

os.environ['DB_URL']="postgresql://usernm:passwd1@localhost:5432/my_db"

from tasks import app as application
application.secret_key = '\x04\xf5\\VN:\xb7\xb9\xca\x95\xa3m!4@\x17\xfcg\xe5\xe2q\x05'
```

The browser url after activating the apache web server: http://localhost/rt1 gives 404 error

The apache log shows: mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.2 as warning. Please let me know what I need to fix to get this configuration working?

Comment: _"The apache log shows: mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.2 as warning"_. What version of python is installed in your python virtual environment? The first directory configured for the python-path option of `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive is a file path. You need to correct that to the folder containing `wsgi.py` module for your application.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule 1.Changed WSGIDaemonProcess to tasks4 python-path=/home/user1/Projects/tasks/tasks/tasks/ and tried. 2.Couldn't find mod_wsgi compiled with python/3.6 either. Hence posted. Besides it is just a warning and no error. Any other problems you could find?

Answer (score 0):

`python-home` option of `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive should be set.

Activate your virtual environment where `mod_wsgi` is installed in terminal.

Run command, `python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"` in terminal, copy output, and set it for `python-home` option.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess tasks4 python-path=/home/user1/Projects/tasks/tasks/tasks python-home=<sys_prefix_value_in_virtual_env>
```

Remove manual activation of virtual environment in `wsgi.py` module.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

os.environ['DB_URL']="postgresql://usernm:passwd1@localhost:5432/my_db"

from tasks import app as application
application.secret_key = '\x04\xf5\\VN:\xb7\xb9\xca\x95\xa3m!4@\x17\xfcg\xe5\xe2q\x05'
```

Look at `python-path` option and be sure that `/home/user1/Project/tasks/tasks/tasks` is root folder of your project.

Comment: Which mod_wsgi should be installed? systemwide install for mod_wsgi: apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3  is what I have done. Within virtualenv: I cannot install: $ pip install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Comment: I have created my virtualenv in /home/user1 folder which I activate for another project also

Comment: When the command is run in the virtualenv, python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"  I get '/usr/local' . Systemwide also python 3.6 is installed

Comment: `sys.prefix` value in your virtual environment is incorrect. I recommend to setup a separate virtual environment for the project. Check that `sys.prefix` value changes from `/usr/local` to the folder of containing `python` in the new virtual environment. You can install `mod_wsgi` in the virtual environment by running `pip install mod_wsgi`. See *Installation into Python* section of the [package page](https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/).

Comment: (env_dms_rt) user1@debian:~/Projects/tasks$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"
/usr/local
(env_dms_rt) user1@debian:~/Projects/tasks$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"
/home/user1/Projects/tasks/env_dms_rt
How to check which is being used?